# Windows Phone 7 Streaming Audio Basic Authentication

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, streaming

I am trying to play a password protected Icecast stream from Windows Phone Application.

```
        UriBuilder station = new UriBuilder();
        station.Host="myhost";
        station.Port=80;
        station.Password = "password";
        station.UserName = "user";
        station.Path = "path";
        station.Scheme = "http";

        Uri stationUrl = station.Uri;
        Debug.WriteLine(stationUrl);
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(stationUrl, "asd", "abc", "asd", null);
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
```

I even tried using

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://user:password@host:port/path", UriKind.Absolute), "abc", "as", "de", null);
```

It could not play. But when I remove username and password it can play.

Authentication is taking place using a PHP file. When I checked the authentication results by printing the $_POST values, they were blank. The same URL works in VLC, Firefox not in IE though.

Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: Did you manage to play by authenticating?